# C# : how to retrieve session as an object from view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I make a session called `CartItem` where it stores products when an user select a product.

My problem is I want to retrieve the session `CartItem` as an object by using deserilize but the compiler says it has null value.

This is my `CartItem` model class:

```
public class CartItem
{
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            public string ProductName { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
            public float Price { get; set; }

            public float Total
            {
                    get { return Quantity * Price; }
            }

            public string Image { get; set; }

            public CartItem()
            {
            }

            public CartItem(Product product)
            {
                    ProductId = product.ID;
                    ProductName = product.Name;
                    Price = product.Price;
                    Quantity = 1;
            }
}
```

This is how I create the session

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    //convert from object to binary
    public static void SetJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        // Set the given key and value in the current session. 
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    // convert from binary to object
    public static T GetJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var sessionData = session.GetString(key);
        //null return default
        return sessionData == null ? default : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(sessionData);
    }
}
```

This is my `CartController`:

```
public class CartController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;
    string baseURL = "https://localhost:7177/";

    private ServiceConnection connectToAPI;

    public CartController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        connectToAPI = new ServiceConnection();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // if.getJson is null then create new List CartItem object
        List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart") ?? new List<CartItem>();

        CartViewModel cartVM = new()
        {
            CartItems = cart,
            //LINQ iterate and sum all the items in cart
            GrandTotal = cart.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price)
        };

        return View(cartVM);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int id)
    {
        // Consume API
        Product product = new Product();
       
        connectToAPI.UseUrl += "api/products/" + id;

        // Check response
        HttpResponseMessage getData = await connectToAPI.CallServiceGet();

        if (getData.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string results = getData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            // convert data from SQL to Product object and will be used 
            product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(results);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }

        // Product product = await _context.Product.FindAsync(id);
        // WANT THIS LIST CARTiTEM iN   IN ORDERLINE
        List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart") ?? new List<CartItem>();

        CartItem cartItem = cart.Where(c => c.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (cartItem == null)
        {  
            cart.Add(new CartItem(product));
        }
        else
        {
            cartItem.Quantity += 1;
        }

        HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
        TempData["Success"] = "The product has been added!";

        //same as return RedirectToAction("index","Products");
        return Redirect(Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
    }
}
```

This is the view

```
@model CartViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cart Overview";
}

@if (Model.CartItems.Count > 0)
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Sub Total</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ProductName</td>
                <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId">+</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" asp-action="Decrease" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId">-</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId">Remove</a>
                </td>
                <td>@item.Price kr.</td>
                <td>@Model.CartItems.Where(x => x.ProductId == item.ProductId).Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price) kr.</td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right" colspan="4"> Total: @Model.GrandTotal kr.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right" colspan="4">
                <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-action="Clear">Clear Cart</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Create" asp-route-CartItem="@Model.CartItems">Checkout</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
else
{
    <h3 class="display-4 text-center">Your cart is empty.</h3>
}
```

I am not sure if I am doing it right, I use

```
asp-route-CartItem="@Model.CartItems"
```

to pass the `CartItems` when user presses checkout to method `Create` in `OrdersController`.

```
   <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Create" asp-route-CartItem="@Model.CartItems">Checkout</a>
```

And here is the `OrderController` where there is a method `Create` that I want to convert session `CartItem` as an object so I can get values like `cartItem.productId`, `cartItem.Price` but it doesn't work:

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
    CustomerServiceConnection cusService = new CustomerServiceConnection();
    OrderServiceConnection orderService = new OrderServiceConnection();

    CustomerDatabaseAccessa _customerAccess;

    public OrdersController(IConfiguration inConfiguration)
    {
        _customerAccess = new CustomerDatabaseAccessa(inConfiguration);
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: ShapesController/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Customers/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Customer customer, Order order, CartItem cartItem )
    {
            DateTime insertedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            int customerId = await cusService.SaveCustomer(customer);
            order = new(customerId, insertedDateTime);
            int orderId = await orderService.SaveOrder(order);

            HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cartItem);
        
            CartItem item = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<CartItem>("Cart");
            // the value here are 0 I'm not sure why
            OrderLine orderline = new OrderLine(item.ProductId, 90, item.Quantity, item.Total);
            _customerAccess.CreateOrderLine(orderline);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            // OrderLine orderline = new OrderLine(1, 66, 2, 10);
            // Customer da = new("Adam", "Star", "4564566", "123@gmaill.com");
            //  int cusId = _customerAccess.CreateCustomera(da);
            //  Order ad = new(returnCustomerId, insertedDateTime);

            //int orderId = _customerAccess.CreateOrder(ad);
            // int OrderLine = _customerAccess.CreateOrderLine(orderId, cusId, etc);

            //  Order orderOBJ = new(cus.Id, order.orderDate); */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `asp-route-CartItem` is invalid. You'd better convert it to JSON and pass as a string. You get `null` value because you set `null` value — no `CartItem` is passed to your action method.

Use this link:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Orders/Create?cartItem=@(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.CartItems))">Checkout</a>
```

Make parameter `cartItem`'s type `string`, and deserialize it inside the method:

```cs
var cartItemObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CartItem>(cartItem);
```

Comment: Thank for your time but it still shows null value

Comment: Does it show any error messages (look in the developer tools, too)? And show me the link's markup ([here](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2018/05/01/live-editing-html-css-chrome-devtools/) are instructions how to access HTML code of a page in Chrome). Consider finding the link's tag, copying its code and pasting it to a comment.

Comment: I solved it by using TempData